# Elastic Beanstalk forms.py not found (works locally)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am getting the following errors on AWS Beanstalk:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/python/current/app/silverwebapp/application.py", line 4, in <module>
     from forms import CommentForm
 ImportError: No module named forms
```

When I run this locally, everything works. I do not know why "forms" doesn't exist here.

This is my folder structure:

```
SilverWeb/
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── silverwebapp
    ├── application.py
    ├── application.pyc
    ├── config.py
    ├── config.pyc
    ├── db_create.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── forms.pyc
    ├── static
    │   ├── startbootstrap-grayscale
    │   └── static
    └── templates
        ├── hello.html
        └── submit.html
```

This is my .ebextensions/static.config:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
    option_name: /static/
    value: silverwebapp/static/
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: StaticFiles
    value: /static/=silverapp/static/
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: silverwebapp/application.py
```

I can confirm that when I ssh into my elastic bean instance via `eb ssh`, the file "forms.py" does exist.

Why am I getting this error that no module named forms exist? Clearly, forms.py exist in the folder containing application.py

Answer (score 0):

So I tried a couple of things and found that adding this to .ebextensions helped.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: PYTHONPATH
    value: "/opt/python/current/app/silverwebapp:$PYTHONPATH"
```

It seems silly that this is needed.